# Just 8,4 GB free in share me

Tags: ubuntu-one

i just bought 20 GB extra, but when I try to access the shareme folder and copy my backup folder (9,8 GB) it says it's just 8,4 GB available. According to the account it should be 25. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to wait?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running out of space physically on your hard disk?

Comment: oh, maybe, but i thought it was the cloud disk i was copying them to. Do i need to have enough space on an extra folder locally?

Comment: Yep. A copy of the data is stored locally as well as remotely so you need enough space locally to hold the data.

Comment: I was going to convert this to a comment, but I suspect it's probably the answer in this case.